# Stop admin-ajax.php from firing after calling function on button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a created button in my `post.php` screen where you can generate and download a PDF using the `fpdf` libary. I've got this working by using a function and then firing it if the $_POST isset. I'm then calling this on the `admin_init` like so:

```
 add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'my_function_with_wc_functions'));

function my_function_with_wc_functions() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['generate_posts_pdf'] ) ) {

      $post_id = $_POST['pageid'];

      if ( isset( $_POST['_close_competition_early'] ) ) {
        $complete = false;
      }

      else {
        $complete = true;
      }

      $this->output_pdf( $post_id, $complete );
    }


  <form method="post" id="as-fdpf-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="pageid" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
        <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_posts_pdf" value="generate">Generate PDF from Competiion Entries</button>
        <button class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="generate_posts_csv" value="generate">Generate CSV from Competiion Entries</button>
      </form>


function output_pdf( $id, $complete ) {
    global $wpdb;

      if ( $complete ) {
        $table = "tickets";
      }

      else {
        $table = "tickets_regenerated";
      }

      if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.$table.' WHERE lottery_id= %d AND used = %d', $id, 1 ) ) ) {

      $log = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.$table.' WHERE lottery_id=%d AND used = %d', $id, 1 ) );

      global $pdf;
      $title_line_height = 10;
      $content_line_height = 8;

      $pdf->AddPage('L');
      $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 42 );

      $header = array('Order Number', 'Full name (Billing)', 'Draw #');

      $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', 'B', 8);
      $pdf->Cell(20,5,'Order Number', 1);
      $pdf->Cell(35,5, 'Full name (billing)', 1);
      $pdf->Cell(25,5, 'Draw #' ,1);

      $pdf->Ln();

      $i = 0;
      foreach( $log as $row ) {
        if($i%2 == 0) :
            $pdf->setFillColor(255,255,255);
        else :
            $pdf->setFillColor(230,230,230);
        endif;
            $pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 8 );
            $pdf->Cell(20,5,$row->order_id, 1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(35,5, $row->full_name,1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Cell(25,5,$row->ticket_number,1, 0, 'C', true);
            $pdf->Ln();
       $i++;
          }
        }

    $upload = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_dir = $upload['basedir'];
    $upload_dir = $upload_dir . '/entry-lists/'.$id;
     if (! is_dir($upload_dir)) {
       mkdir( $upload_dir, 0700 );
    }

    $pdf->Output('D', $id.'.pdf', true);
    $pdf->Output('F', $upload_dir.'/'.$id.'.pdf', true);


    exit;
}
```

The problem I have is that once the PDF has downloaded, the page automatically fires the `admin-ajax.php` and creates an autosave which causes the update button to be disabled.

I've tried adding `event.preventDefault();` to the button this stops the button from working.

Is there a way I can stop the admin-ajax.php from firing after I've clicked the button?

Comment: "once the PDF has downloaded, the page automatically fires the admin-ajax.php"....does it? Where is the code to do that, you haven't shown it. If you don't want it to do that, try removing that code.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I believe the ajax is firing  because the post autosaves and shows this message 'The backup of this post in your browser is different from the version below'. Also, when i look at the console and the network tab, admin-ajax.php is being called

Comment: Ok but I'm not really asking you to prove it, I'm asking for the code you wrote to make it happen. Because presumably that's the code you need to change or get rid of in order to stop it from happening. If you didn't write the code, you'll have to do some searching or debugging in your page to try and find it. If you set your JS debugger to step through the code line by line you should find it fairly quickly I'd imagine.